# Printf doesnt pop

Tags: c++, printf

I'm new to programming in c++ and I'm facing a problem following lynda.com tutorials. It seems okay on the tutorial video but this isnt working with me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { max_string = 127 };

static char string[max_string + 1 ] = "";

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    printf("Type a string: ");
    fgets(string, max_string, stdin);
    printf("The string is %s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

And when I run this something blank appears and I need when I right something like "hey" in the blanket space, this happens:

```
hey
Type a string: The string is hey
```

This is completely strange for me and I have no idea what Im doing wrong tbh.
I'm using Eclipse btw.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Probably not the canonical solution but add `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf` statement, that should do it.

Comment: A C++ tutorial that tells you to use a static char array for user input and printf/fgets? *Run!*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: @us2012 - at least it isn't using `gets(string)`!

Comment: May I humbly suggest http://www.cplusplus.com/ and their excellent tutorials?

Comment: @CharlesBurns : I really hope that was intended to be ironic...

Comment: @ildjarn: It wasn't. Their tutorials do not cover the finer points of  , which user2074085 might find useful in 5 years, but for a basic ANSI C++ tutorial, it explains things well and has nicely formatted, easy-to-understand, step-by-step tutorials.

Comment: @CharlesBurns : http://stackroulette.com/programmers/88241/undefined

Comment: @ildjarn: We're in a question involving `"Enter a string"` --> `"Here's your string"` and criticize a tutorial website that "omits vital information [about] iterator invalidation"?
I consider the paucity of errors in so large a site and by so pedantic an analysis to be confirmation of its quality, not evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your standard output stream is line-buffered, meaning that text you print doesn't appear until you've printed a complete line. It *should* be unbuffered if you're writing to an interactive device; perhaps something is preventing the system from being aware that the output device is interactive.

Adding

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after your first `printf` should force the `"Type a string: "` prompt to appear immediately (and even if your output is unbuffered, `fflush(stdout)` is harmless).

I was about to suggest changing your second `printf` from:

```
printf("The string is %s", string);
```

to:

```
printf("The string is %s\n", string);
```

to ensure that your program's output ends with a newline (some systems can misbehave if it isn't) -- but `fgets()` actually leaves the newline in your string (unless the input line was very long).  Eventually you'll want to be able to deal with that kind of thing.